# Cannot get docker image of gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.14.0:latest

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision, vision, automl

I got an error when I was trying to download the docker image from

gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.14.0:latest

But I got an error of Access Denied. How can I solve this issue? Thanks a lot.

```html
$ export CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH=gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.14.0:latest
$ docker pull ${CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH}
Error response from daemon: Get https://gcr.io/v2/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.14.0/manifests/latest: denied: Permission denied: Consumer 'project:automl-vision-ondevice' has been suspended.
```

Comment: Your image is running or not, did you check that?

Comment: No. I have checked that the image did not pull successful today. I was pulled successfully last week. But just got the error today when I tried out on another machine.

Comment: I am not sure if it is the issue from GCP Docker Registry or not. Coz I was completely following the instruction of https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial.

Comment: Based on the message error: `Consumer 'project:automl-vision-ondevice' has been suspended.` Can you check if your project still available or restricted in some ways?

Comment: I am not sure if it is still available. The project is owned by GCP Vision and I was following the instructions to pull the image, then wanna to try out the trained model with it.

Comment: And I have no idea how to contact the google customer service. coz I am a personal user, they have not provided any technical support. According to the suggest of Help in GCP. They only suggest me to ask my question in Stack overflow.

Comment: You can find some help by following this [link](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/9664343), based on the message error you provided, there's something wrong with your project. You can also try to contact the [billing support](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. Luckily i changed the language of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/automl/docs/containers-gcs-tutorial#pull_the_docker_image) to english and found another URL under which the Docker image is located. The Google team has probably moved the image.

Change

```
$ export CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH=gcr.io/automl-vision-ondevice/gcloud-container-1.14.0:latest
```

to

```
$ export CPU_DOCKER_GCR_PATH=gcr.io/cloud-devrel-public-resources/gcloud-container-1.14.0:latest
```